# Is there any way to get all records by given value in a list using CrudRepository from DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, crud-repository

I'm trying to get all the records from 'Messages' table but the problem is 'roles' are saving as an array in dynamo DB and I need to get all records which having the "INSTRUCTOR" role of each record.

**Available records are as follows in dynamoDB.**

***Record 1***

{
"product": "Maths",
"messageSummary": "test message",
"roles": [
"ADMIN",
"INSTRUCTOR"
],
"title": "My course1",
"createdBy": 0,
"authorName": "test author",
"id": "1"
}

***Record 2***

{
"product": "Maths",
"messageSummary": "test message",
"roles": [
"STUDENT"
],
"title": "My course2",
"createdBy": 0,
"authorName": "test author",
"id": "2"
}

***Record 3***

{
"product": "Maths",
"messageSummary": "test message",
"roles": [
"INSTRUCTOR",
"STUDENT"
],
"title": "My course3",
"createdBy": 0,
"authorName": "test author",
"id": "3"
}

**Message model class as follows which referring "Messages" table**

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Messages")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @ApiModelProperty(accessMode = ApiModelProperty.AccessMode.READ_ONLY, position = 1)
    private String id;

    /* authorName, messageSummary, title .. attributes goes here */

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, allowableValues = "maths", position = 6)
    private Product product;

    @ApiModelProperty(allowableValues = "student, instructor, admin", position = 7)
    private List<Role> roles;


    // getters and setters
}
```

**Message repository as follows which extends CrudRepository**

```
@EnableScan
public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, String> {

    List<Message> findMessageByProductAndRoles(Product product, List roles); // Need to filter by given role
}
```

Since I need to get all the records that have INSTRUCTOR role, **Record 1 and Record 3** should be in the result list. However, I can filter it only using the product value but am not able to filter using roles.

Additionally, I tried this using some keywords such as **Contains, Like, In** etc. but those are not succeeded for me. as per my observation, those keywords are not supporting to filter a specific value from an array.

And getting this **error**:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-01-27T08:42:54.786+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: One or more parameter values were invalid: ComparisonOperator CONTAINS is not valid for SS AttributeValue type (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: xxxxxxx)",
    "path": "/api/xxx/my route"
}
```

**How can I achieve that and implement such conditions using the CrudRepository?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many options to query for the database, I was able to get relevant records lists by implementing GSI in DynamoDB. Since I'm using java I have used QuerySpec to get them.

```
QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("lifeCycle = :life_cycle AND startDate < :s_date")
                .withFilterExpression("contains (#user_roles, :roles))
                .withNameMap(expressionAttributeNames)
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                        .withString(":life_cycle", lifeCycle)
                        .withString(":roles", userRole)
                        .with(":s_date", startDate)
                );

        ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = index.query(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you pointed out, you cannot use those operators (`CONTAINS`, `LIKE`, `IN`) in a filter expression.

> One or more parameter values were invalid: ComparisonOperator CONTAINS is not valid for SS AttributeValue type

[FilterExpression criteria follows that of the KeyConditionExpression, with the addition of the not-equals operator.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression)

It seems like your current table structure is incompatible with this access pattern. DynamoDB only works as a solution when the base table is designed around the access patterns, extending the base table's capabilities when necessary with the addition secondary indexes.

One option would be to simply query by the partition key (and sort key if applicable) and let your application do the filtering. DynamoDB `FilterExpressions` are applied *after the initial query* (or scan) is completed anyway, so you pay for all the data you've read. The filter simply returns less than that to your application. There's no real performance or cost benefit besides whatever comes from offloading the burden from your application to DyanamoDB.

Another option, rather than adjusting your key structure, would be to leverage secondary indexes. More specifically, [sparse indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html) (multiple in your case, one for each role), but only if you have the flexibility break out that `String Set` attribute into several "key friendly" values. You cannot use `Sets` as keys. Keep in mind, the practicality of a secondary indexes entirely depends entirely on the nature of the access pattern.

When thinking about creating an index for your base table, you should always ask yourself:

> Does this query happen frequently enough to justify the cost of a secondary index?

If the answer to that is yes, you should then also ask yourself:

> Am I projecting enough of the right attributes to the new index so that I can avoid charges for updating unused projections, and for fetches of missing projections?

After those questions, there is plenty to more to consider, including Secondary Indexes [fundamentals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) and [best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes.html).

Comment: Thanks for giving instructions. I was able to get a list of records using GSI. but now I'm facing another problem with filtering expressions. I just asked that question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71311852/how-to-find-empty-array-values-in-dynamodb-gsi

Appreciate it if you can give me any suggestions to implement such scenario.